# Multiple arguments in znapzendzetup --tsformat?

Tags: znapzend

I was wondering if `znapzendzetup --tsformat` option can take multiple arguments? I.e. one per interval/retention period.

Comment: No, the format must be consistent over time. What would be the use case for this?

Comment: My previous snapshots were named by the type. E.g. frequent, hourly, daily, weekly and monthly. Although using a single name for future snap shots is fine.

Comment: You will  have to rename your old snapshots.